# ruby - get cookie from response when there are two or more set-cookie headers

Tags: ruby

This is just pure ruby not rail.

I'm trying to code an auto login form to change some configurations of my web hosting panel.
There are two and more cookies returned.

I wish to get ruby version of this post
[How to handle multiple Set-Cookie header in HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649401/how-to-handle-multiple-set-cookie-header-in-http-response)

open-uri also takes the last set-cookie header.

h1 = open("http://www.w3.org/")
h1.meta['set-cookie']

Answer (score 0):

`get_fields()` solves this problem.